# what is the use of binary-or if using same values? (segment tree)

Tags: c++, binary, segment-tree

Can't understand the requirement of t[i<<1|1] in build() function of seg tree.
isn't it equivalent to **t[i<<1]** ?

````
const int N = 1e5;  // limit for array size
int n;  // array size
int t[2 * N];

void build() {  // build the tree
  for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; --i) t[i] = t[i<<1] + t[i<<1|1];
}

void modify(int p, int value) {  // set value at position p
  for (t[p += n] = value; p > 1; p >>= 1) t[p>>1] = t[p] + t[p^1];
}

int main() {
  scanf("%d", &n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) scanf("%d", t + n + i);
  build();
  modify(0, 1);
  printf("%d\n", query(3, 11));
  return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Do you know [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)?

Comment: `i<<1|1` is an unnecessarily obfuscated way to write `i*2 + 1`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, A particular group (read sect) of programmers think left shifting is faster over multiplication... for an unknown reason